# See if console is closing

Tags: java

I have a server that is constantly running, and when I go to close it, I need it to detect that it is closing so it automatically closes the socket. Is there anyway to see if the console is closing? I'm not using Java2D or anything like that though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
                       //Shutdown here
        }
    }));
```

This is closest you'll get to what your looking for...